# How do I derive a correlation coefficient from a table of T values?

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to figure out what is the magnitude of a correlation reported in a scientific article from the table that is provided in the paper. I am not a statistician but I generally read papers and understand the basics. However, in this case, the statistics is too complex for me and I would really appreciate some help.. I am explaining my struggle below and I am pasting the Table here[image].

In the text the authors state that a cardiological variable (HF-HRV) is negatively correlated with brain structure variables (e.g. insula volume), but they give no correlation coefficient. I need to compare this result with my own findings (I used Spearman's correlations). I read the statistics section of the article and apparently a multiple linear regression was carried out with HF-HRV as IV, insula volume as DV and demographics as potential confounders. So I assume the correlation they talk about is the square of $R^2$ from the regression.

I have done some research and found a thread that explains how to calculate $r$ from a t value [enter link description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281801/how-to-calculate-critical-values-for-r-for-a-large-dataset)
I was wondering if the t values reported in the Table are the t-values the thread is talking about, in which case I can calculate $r$ for the insula (= -0.22) and I can see that the correlation is weak.

I hope someone can reach out to me.

Comment: It's a multiple regression. I see no way to get a correlation (root of R-square) without a sample size.  In any case that would hardly be comparable with your Spearman correlations for individual pairs of variable. Why not ask the authors for their data?

Comment: The T is most likely the t-statistic of the HF-HRV coefficient from the multiple regression and they interpret the T in terms of correlation with your dependent variable, which is not wrong. Note that they are doing a multiple regression to control for so called "demographic factors" , and I don't know if this or other factors exist in your data

Comment: Bottom line is you cannot really compare them directly. Best way is for you to get the data, and analysis it using spearman correlation, keeping in mind the demographic / other factors involved in their study

Comment: @Nick Cox, I do have the sample size (n=185). If I apply the formula r=t/√[t2 +(n-2)] I get an r of -0.22. Would this be the correlation coefficient I am looking for? I just need to have an idea of the effect size so that I can compare it to my results. My Spearman's correlations are actually partial correlations because I, too, am controlling for some other variables..Thank you all

Comment: My suggestion remains to ask for the authors' data. That's the only way to apply the same methods.

Comment: @Nick Cox, thank you for following up on the question. I get your point. However, when you said I would have needed a sample size were you referring to the possibility of using the t to r formula as I did? I would really like to know, just for the sake of learning. I will contact the authors, but , in my experience, researchers do not easily give access to their data and I would have to ask them to do the statistics for me. That is why I was trying to find a way round it, even a very rough and approximate one.

Comment: Not knowing the sample size was sufficient to rule out a solution but there are other barriers. I don't work in your field but if I wouldn't expect authors in my field to try such an exercise. If the authors won't provide data, you are home free: you can just write "The data were not available".